# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strtolower(): enable mbstring on linux EC2

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed the mbstring through `sudo yum install php-mbstring`on my linux EC2 instance with php 5.6.17. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 4):

need to use yum install php56-mbstring. Once I install it, no need to config, just restart the httpd service